# Take individual MySQL database offline

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

MySQL does not have any SQL commands or internal mechanisms for

- making an individual database unavailable / offline
- moving an individual database

Thtis being the case, how can you take an individual database offline?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a suitable answer, but would achieve your goal...

What about, for the time you want it offline, renaming the database? This way, whatever application you have accessing the data would fail to connect to the database.

Moving the database can be achieved by

```
mysqldump -u user -p database -c > whatever.sql
```

Then import `whatever.sql` into another server, finally dropping the original DB.

Answer (score -1):

This behavior could be achieved programmatically...

Create a table of databases and the status you would like them to be..  then your application can test the status of the database prior to use..   the application proceeds if the status is available and returns a message if unavailable.

You could also do this with applications in general too (same thing as described above but with application instead)...  You can then control applications use of the instance.